# static_cast dynamic_cast: expected constant expression?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In visual C++ 2010, when compiling the following codes, I get error message:

static_cast error C2057: expected constant expression.

what's wrong with that?

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

struct XX
{
    static const int offset = (long)static_cast<A*>((B*)0x8) - 0x8;
};
```

Thanks AProgrammer, the following is correct for VC 2010:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

struct XX
{
    static const int offset;
};

const int XX::offset
 = (long)static_cast<A const*>((B const*)0x8) - 0x8;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you mixing C-style casts and C++ casts? This doesn't really aid readability IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your casts to A* and B* prevent the initializer of x to be a constant expression:

5.19/3

> Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert arithmetic or enumeration types to arithmetic or enumeration types, excepted as part of an operand to the `sizeof` operator.

which is needed in that context:

9.2/4

> A *member-declarator* can contain a *constant-initializer* only if it declares a `static` member of integral or enumeration type.

Comment: struct A {};
struct B : A {};

struct XX
{
 static const int x = (long)static_cast<A const*>((B const*)0x8) - 0x8;
};

Comment: @niexw, I don't understand.  As long as you cast to or from pointer types -- constant or not -- you don't have a constant expression for the purpose of that initializer.

Comment: @niexw, Not in a constant expression for arithmetic values.

Comment: (B*)0x8 is an arithmetic value?

Comment: these codes are compiled successfully with g++, I can not find the error.

Comment: All g++ versions I've tried says here: _a cast to a type other than an integral or enumeration type cannot appear in a constant-expression_

Comment: @niexw, you are initializing offset as a static const member, the initializer needs to be a constant expression and the casts prevent that.

Comment: how can I get the static const offset in compiling time?

Comment: I get what you say. In visual C++ 2010, static const A* can not be initialized with in the class, so VC forbiden the static_cast<A*> appear in the expression?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just say:

```
static const int x =0x8;
```